# How to add class="alt" to every odd row/tr inside table?

Tags: templates, jinja2

I am generating table and fill from dictionary inside Jinja2 template like

```
<table>
{% for key, value in template_values.iteritems() %}
    <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

How to add class="alt" to every odd row/tr inside table ?
(At the moment I am using jquery and on ready I set but is there way to do this while generating template)

Comment: <ul>
{% for row in rows %}
  <li class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}">{{ row }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul> i hope it's useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at alternating rows in the Jinja docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/